# Angular 1.x - How to display table with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: angularjs, dynamic-tables, angular1.6

Aim - Display a dynamic table for both rows and columns as below -

[image]

Dynamic Header - The fund codes are values for "name" from the json object array.

Dynamic rows with values for Application, Redemption and Net

JSON object :

```
[
            {
                name: 'VBIF',
                application: 1000,
                redemption: -200,
                netAppRed: 800
            },
            {
                name: 'VCIF',
                application: 1500,
                redemption: -200,
                netAppRed: 800
            },
            {
                name: 'VMPF',
                application: 2000,
                redemption: 0,
                netAppRed: 2000
            },
            {
                name: 'VBIF-A',
                application: 800,
                redemption: 100,
                netAppRed: 700
            },
            {
                name: 'VMPF-A',
                application: 43540,
                redemption: 12550,
                netAppRed: 30990
            }
        ]
```

HTML :

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fund Code</th>
                    <th>Application</th>
                    <th>Redemption</th>
                    <th>Net Application Redemption</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">
                    <td>{{cashflow.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{cashflow.application | currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{cashflow.redemption | currency}}</td>
                    <td>{{cashflow.netAppRed | currency}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Current view displays :

[image]

Comment: Can you not modify the JSON data as per the display output you want?

Comment: The service is developed by another team, but yes, its an option(last resort).

Comment: Well, it should be your first option. You can modify the structure of the returned data as per your need by applying JavaScript array functions like map etc. This is necessary in your case as the HTML table is generated row by row using `<tr>` upon array members. If your array members are in a format, then displaying is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Another option without need to change model:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fund Code</th>

                    <th data-ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">{{cashflow.name}} </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr >
                    <td>Application</td>
                    <td data-ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">{{cashflow.application | currency}}</td>

                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td>Redemption</td>
                    <td data-ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">{{cashflow.redemption | currency}}</td>

                </tr>
                <tr >
                    <td>NetAppRed</td>
                    <td data-ng-repeat="cashflow in cashflows">{{cashflow.netAppRed | currency}}</td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Neat! Thank you Agam :)

Answer (score 0):

Resovled it by changing the model in the controller as below -

```
$scope.getHeaders = function (){

    var keys = [];
    angular.forEach(object, function (val, key) {
        if(key !== '$$hashKey') { keys.push(key); }
    });
    return keys;
};

$scope.getValue = function () {
    var values = [];
    angular.forEach(object, function (val, key) {
        if(key !== '$$hashKey') { values.push(val); }
    });
    return values;
};
```

The HTML updated as below -

```
               <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th ng-repeat="(header, value) in cashflows">
                            {{value.name}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Application</td>
                        <td ng-repeat="row in cashflows">
                            {{row.application}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Redemption</td>
                        <td ng-repeat="row in cashflows">
                            {{row.redemption}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Net App & Red</td>
                        <td ng-repeat="row in cashflows">
                            {{row.netAppRed}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Final Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-tables to show your dynamic data

here is example

[https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-tables-with-ng-table][1]

if any query ask me on comment